# Retail database for products with unrelated attributes

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I am new to database design, and I'm designing a bookstore database for practice. I have the following tables that allow me to search for books that meet specific criteria:

```
SERIES(series_id (pk),  series_title)

AUTHOR(author_id (pk), author_name, author_country, author_birthdate)

BOOK(book_id(pk), book_title, book_genre, author_id(fk), series_id(fk))
```

However, the store also sells random products (pens, candy, journals, etc.) that also need to be tracked but don't have unique attributes. Would the following be the correct way to structure the 
**INVENTORY** table?

```
INVENTORY(product_ID (pk), Amnt_in_Stock, product_name, product_description, book_id(fk))
```

And would the book_id be an optional 1:1 relationship?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the requirements although this is only a practice for you. If the requirements says separate the inventory for the books from other items then you will have a separate table for that (i.e. other items). Otherwise you make it as one table and you need to find a way to connect the two tables for inventory purpose.

As for creating another table for another Item then that would not be a problem as far as unique identification is concerned, you could make a unique `Item Code` for each item or you could make an `Auto Increment` `Primary Key` for it instead.

For me it's best to separate it because the attributes are varied although there are similarities. Like Book title, genre, ISBN, author could not be said the same for other items like candies, pens and journals for example.

You could make probably like this:

```
SERIES(series_id (pk),  series_title)
AUTHOR(author_id (pk), author_name, author_country, author_birthdate)
BOOK(book_id(pk), book_title, book_genre, author_id(fk), series_id(fk), original_price, selling_price)
OTHER_ITEMS(item_code(pk), description, qty_on_hand, original_price, selling_price)

SOLD_ITEMS(SoldItemID (pk), reference_code (FK), Books (boolean), Qty_Sold, Price_Sold, Date_Sold, Cashier)
```

The `reference_code` would either be `item_code` of `other_items` or `book_id` of `Book` table.

You could probably also add `Supply History` to keep track what's coming on in inventory, like:

```
SUPPLY_HISTORY(SupplyHistoryID (PK), OrderCode, SupplyDate, ReferenceCode, Books (boolean), Quantity, OriginalPrice, SupplierID (FK))
SUPPLIER (SupplierID (PK), SupplierName, Contact_Person, Phone, Email)
```